# How To Split String Before After Comma?

Tags: php, string, split

i have string like this:

```
<?php $string = "52.74837280745686,-51.61665272782557"; ?>
```

i want access to first string before comma and second string after comma  like this:

```
<?php string1 = "52.74837280745686";  $string2 = "-51.61665272782557" ; ?>
```

thank you !

Comment: Have you searched into the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php)? One of the tags you attached to the question is also the name of a [PHP function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) that can help you.

Comment: @JayBlanchard apart from the fact that [`split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php) is deprecated since PHP 5.3 (and removed in PHP 7), `split(',', $string)` works the same as `explode(',', $string)`. Anyway, my point was about reading the documentation. Simple questions like this one always have the answers in the manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite straigtforward

```
<?php

list($string1, $string2) = explode(",", $string);
```

or more excant

```
<?php

$splitTokens = explode(",", $string); // this is what "split" is in other languages, splits an spring by a SEP and retrieving an array
$string1 = $splitTokens[0];
$string2 = $splitTokens[1];
```